# Sharepoint 2013 event to Windows .Net app

Tags: 2013, development

Experienced with .Net, I'm completely new with SharePoint. On my development PC I create a standard standalone .Net app that represent the 'Documents' stored on my SharePoint 2013 (like an explorer). It works like a charm with just two references to `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client` and `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Runtime`

I try now to be notified when somebody make some changes (add/delete/update) on files or folders on the Sharepoint web interface, but I'm stuck. Is it possible ? How does it works ? How could I get events from the server?

Comment: You want get notified in your app when in sharepoint something get updated, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get notified from the SharePoint WebApp on changes. One way could be to call the SharePoint WebServices or check via Client Object Model if there are any changes. But i wouldnt suggest this way when you have multiple libraries and a large number of files cause this is not very performant.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to deploy a custom SharePoint solution (could be a farm WSP solution or an "App", sorry an "add-in"). That solution contains an event event receiver (would be a *remote* one in case of an App). That ER would call a Web service, hosting "something capable of notifying your client app" (e.g. a basic TCP server, that your app would have connected at launch). That "something" could even be hosted on your SP server (if on-premises).